# Strange Error in Java ME

Tags: java, multithreading, mobile, java-me, midlet

I've just starting delving into the wonders of Java ME but have become frustrated when trying to create a thread...

Below is the code which compiles absolutely fine. However, as soon as I install it on my G600 and run it, 'Java Game Error' pops up.

My method of putting it in a jar file and installing it works, as I have created a game with no threads and that works fine.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.game.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

public class CanvasTest extends MIDlet {
Display display;

public CanvasTest() {

}

public void startApp() {
  TestCanvas thecanvas = new TestCanvas();
  display = Display.getDisplay(this);
  display.setCurrent(thecanvas);
}

public void pauseApp() {}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {}
}
class TestCanvas extends GameCanvas implements Runnable {
Font font;

int width;
int height;

boolean running = true;

public TestCanvas() {
    super(false);
    setFullScreenMode(true);
    width = getWidth();
    height = getHeight();
    Thread thisThread = new Thread(this);
    thisThread.start();

}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    g.setColor(rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

}
public void run() {
  while(running) {
    paint(getGraphics());

    flushGraphics();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } 
    catch(InterruptedException ex) {}
  }
}
};
```

Note: yes, this is not the game, it merely demonstrates the problem I am facing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you test it at emulator prior to phone? if not - why? if yes - how did it go?

regarding the code it looks OK to me except for the *slippery* two lines where you create and start thread from constructor. I'd rather move these two lines at the end of `startApp`

```
public void startApp() {
    TestCanvas theCanvas= new TestCanvas();
    display = Display.getDisplay(this);
    display.setCurrent(theCanvas);
    new Thread(theCanvas).start(); // add here and...
}
//...
public TestCanvas() {
    super(false);
    setFullScreenMode(true);
    width = getWidth();
    height = getHeight();
    // ...and remove here
    // Thread thisThread = new Thread(this);
    // thisThread.start();
}
```

Comment: Suggestion didn't alter the outcome, in fact this was my first approach and the posted code was an attempt at a work around (sorry about that).

I will get back to you on how the emulator fares.

Comment: very interesting - please post when you get an update. Also, did you somehow test/verify that re-installation happened indeed? I mean if there was some failure installing updated version then the outcome you observed might indeed be one of prior version? I'd check this with something like re-installing and launching "threadless" version (one that you mentioned worked fine) then re-installing most up-to-date again. Or better yet I'd create a 'splash screen' that displays first and shows some version identifier. Could be a simple form with textfield and a command 'Start'

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, I have a confession to make: I like to do things the 'manual' way - I was using the compile + add to jar + adjust jad, etc method... It turns out when using the SDK all works perfectly fine in the emulator and on the phone.

I do intend to find out my mistake, and I will post back here if I do find out what went wrong.

Credit to gnat though, for his suggestion of an emulator in the first place and generally helpful tips afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess, but a general rule in Java is that you can't "touch" the UI out of the main thread. Well, this a little bit roughly explained, but there are many articles about the topic.

I suggest you to avoid calling UI methods like `paint()` or `flushGraphics()` from a separate Thread.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I would have thought the
    display.setCurrent(thecanvas);
would allow this...

Anyhow, many examples seem to use this approach